# Selecting from two tables with 1st row from the second table

Tags: sql-server, select, sum

**Table** `ACCOUNT(Name, Debit, Credit)`

```
Name    | Debit  | Credit
=========================
Ram     | 2,000  | 2,000
Bheem   | 3,000  | 3,000
Soorya  | 2,500  | 1,750
John    | 3,500  | 2,500
Abdul   | 1,600  | 00000
Soorya  | 1,500  | 00000
```

**Table** `CLIENTS(Name, ContactNumber)`

```
Name   | ContactNumber
======================
Ram    | 900800
Bheem  | 900700
Soorya | 900600
John   | 900400
Abdul  | 900100
John   | No Value
```

**SQL**

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Debit), SUM(Credit) 
FROM ACCOUNT 
WHERE SUM(Credit)<>SUM(Debit) 
GROUP BY Name & ContactNumber 
FROM CLIENTS WHERE ACCOUNT.Name=CLIENTS.Name
```

If the Name of client exists twice, Only the 1st ContactNumber should be selected.

Expected result:

```
Name   | SUM(Debit) | SUM(Credit)  | ContactNumber
==================================================
Soorya | 4,000      | 1,750        | 900600
John   | 3,500      | 2,500        | 900400
Abdul  | 1,600      | 0000         | 900100
```

How do I to sort this problem?

Comment: and what is the "First" ? The lowest contact number ? The one which is not null ?

Comment: Will there be case when both contact nos are not null, what should be selected in that scenario?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus No value = '' (A string with no characters)

Comment: @PareshJ 1st contact number should be selected.

Comment: @PareshJ there is no implicit ordering of rows unless you specify an ordering. What do you mean by 1st contact number, you need to be able to specify an order, based upon your table definition the only possible order is numerical (which sounds a bit nonsensical). If you don't specify an order the order could change from query to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but it gave the correct answer on the test data provided

```
WITH tmp
     AS (SELECT Name,
                Sum(Debit)  AS SumDebit,
                Sum(Credit) AS SumCredit
         FROM   accounts
         GROUP  BY Name)
SELECT a.Name,
       a.SumDebit,
       a.SumCredit,
       c.ContactNumber
FROM   tmp a,
       (SELECT Name,
               Max(ContactNumber) AS ContactNumber
        FROM   clients
        GROUP  BY Name) c
WHERE  a.Name = c.Name
       AND a.SumDebit <> a.SumCredit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JOIN statement, linked by the name fields.

`SELECT a.Name, SUM(a.Debit), SUM(a.Credit), DISTINCT(c.ContactNumber) 
 FROM ACCOUNT a
 WHERE SUM(a.Credit) != SUM(a.Debit)
    INNER JOIN CLIENTS c
     ON a.Name = c.Name
 GROUP BY a.Name`

Hope it helps.

Comment: why is that **? and SUM(Debit), SUM(Credit) or SUM(a.Debit), SUM(a.Credit)?? Confusing.

Comment: I am using abbreviated table names, defined when you cal the tables in the FROM section (FROM ACCOUNTS a or FROM CLIENTS c).  You could write them as either a.Debit or ACCOUNTS.Debit, c.Name or CLIENTS.Name.

Comment: I just noticed that I had left your ** comments and a little edit so that you can copy and paste it (without understanding how it works). Any better?